# Show selected tab in TabView in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, tabview

When using TabView in SwiftUI, what can I do to show the selected Tab like in the following picture?

[image]

I've tried creating a VStack within each tab like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State public var tabViewSelection = 0
var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $tabViewSelection) {
        HomeFirstLevel()
            .tabItem {
                VStack {
                    Image("HomeIcon")
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(height: 7)
                        .foregroundColor((tabViewSelection == 0) ? .black : .clear)
                }
            }.tag(0)
        }
    }
}
```

But it's not working.
I can't even seem to add a Rectangle instead of an Image:

```
HomeFirstLevel()
   .tabItem {
       Rectangle()
   }.tag(0)
```

Does TabView not accept shapes?
Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not set shape in tabItem. But you can use `ZStack` to add shape over the tab bar and set the x position.

Here is the demo.

```
struct ContentViewTabDemo: View {
    @State public var tabViewSelection = 0
    
    private var singleTabWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 5
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
            TabView(selection: $tabViewSelection) {
                Color.red
                    .tabItem {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                        }
                    }.tag(0)
                
                Color.blue
                    .tabItem {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                        }
                    }.tag(1)
                
                Color.red
                    .tabItem {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                        }
                    }.tag(2)
                
                Color.blue
                    .tabItem {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                        }
                    }.tag(3)
                
                Color.red
                    .tabItem {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                        }
                    }.tag(4)
            }
            
            Rectangle()
                .offset(x: singleTabWidth * CGFloat(tabViewSelection))
                .frame(width: singleTabWidth, height: 7)
                .padding(.bottom, 2)
                .animation(.default)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]